# After feature retract, it stil remain in feature management page!

Tags: features

Why after a retract the feature remain in Feature Management Page (WEB context)?

ps. the directory on /TEMPLATES/{feature} is not there.

Comment: If it was activated, it will remain

Comment: so, how can I desactivate and get deleted?

Comment: You could hit "Deactive" directly on the page, but if you have aldready uninstalled the solution the FeatureDeactivating event will not be run. What do you really mean with feature retract?

Comment: yes i do it (an uninstall) and now ? (unistall by retract)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lets explain what you did! you had a feature that was built within a wsp, you deployed the wsp to a webapp and then activated the feature... you then decide to remove the wsp but forgot to deactivate the feature leaving you in the position that your currently in!

next time deactivate the feature before removing the wsp, once you remove the wsp it removes the files from the hive folder!

```
stsadm –o deactivatefeature –id FeatureGuidGoesHere -url http://moss-1/sitedirectory/team -force
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262680(v=office.12).aspx

```
stsadm –o uninstallfeature –id FeatureGuidGoesHere -force
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262976(v=office.12).aspx

this will remove the feature regardless!

you could reload wsp and feature (needs to be same name and guid and version number) but you need to use the force attribute to add it back in and do the method above to remove it. using the -force when adding is needed as it would say it already exists but infact it doesnt!

the reason it shows that it exists in your webapp, its still displayed within the sql database table of dbo.Features that has the site id, feature id, web id ect...

before anyone complains that its 2010 and this is stsadm, yes we have powershell for 2010 but you can also use stsadm in 2010. im using stsadm because of the force attribute!

Comment: Thank you Ali, so how can I get FeatureGuid ? if it doenst exist in my Visual Studio Solution? (SharePoint 2010)

Comment: you can use its name or file name if you dont know the guid! http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262680(v=office.12).aspx

it might not work tho for uninstalling the fact that it doesnt exist on feature folder within hive

Comment: to get around it redepoly again with the same feature either in vs or stsadm using the force attribute and then do above!

Comment: i just try it, 

and in fact even the new feature I created with the same name gets another GUI (I guess) so it double the name in features admin page for my dite, but when i Retract it using VS, it gets ok.... So it works Ali, Thank You!

Comment: no problem happy to help

Comment: Everyone has its own preferences, but you can also force uninstallation of the feature via PowerShell (Uninstall-SPFeature (...) -Force)